# How to speed up accessing a list of dicts inside a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda

This may sound like a crazy way of storing data, but I am working with data that is sparse, and in an attempt to save space I have created dataframe where one column is a variable length list of dicts (from 1 to over a dozen dicts with three elements each).  I am trying to access the second element in each dict and make a new column with just a list of those second elements.  I can't actually paste my data, however I can provide an example that closely approximates it.

Imagine I have a dataframe of the attributes of my cats, dogs, and hamsters, and I had 3 cats, 1 dog, and 1 hamster, each with color and fur length data.  I'm basically trying to access a list of specific attributes for each animal type.  Now the code below works just fine.  However if you expand it to over 22,000 rows, it is VERY impossibly slow.  This is probably due to the for loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['cats','dogs','hamsters'],'attributes':[[{'color':'white','fur':'short'},{'color':'black','fur':'long'},{'color':'gray','fur':'long'}],[{'color':'brown','fur':'short'}],[{'color':'brown','fur':'short'}]]})


df['colors']=''
for i in range(len(df)):
  attributes = df.attributes.iloc[i]
  df.loc[i,['colors']] = [list(map(lambda x: x['color'],attributes))]
```

df before:

```
       name                                         attributes
0      cats  [{'color': 'white', 'fur': 'short'}, {'color':...
1      dogs               [{'color': 'brown', 'fur': 'short'}]
2  hamsters               [{'color': 'brown', 'fur': 'short'}]
```

df after:

```
       name  ...                colors
0      cats  ...  [white, black, gray]
1      dogs  ...               [brown]
2  hamsters  ...               [brown]
```

I'm looking for a way to speed up this process, possibly with a lambda function?  Not sure, but there is almost always a way to ditch a for loop, however I'm just not able to see it.

Comment: df.apply will broadcast a function across your dataframe (row-wise or column-wise)

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
l=[[y['color'] for y in x] for x in df.attributes]
l
Out[321]: [['white', 'black', 'gray'], ['brown'], ['brown']]
df['color']=l
```

Comment: Sweet!  I did not know you could daisy-chain list comprehensions like that, and I didn't know that it worked for dicts too.  Blazingly fast in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with function first (which can easily be a lambda if you want) and the dataframe.apply() method.

```
def extract_colors(x): 
    return list(map(lambda a: a["color"], x)) 

df["colors"] = df.attributes.apply(extract_colors)
```

If anything this should have a lower memory footprint as the function is broadcast across the dataframe/series and no large intermediate list is created.